"Install TensorFlow and Gym with Conda for usage with Jupyter Notebook in macOS Sonoma, Intel processor
I am trying to set up a virtual environment using Conda to code a lab activity regarding RL, but it is proving to be quite a nightmare due to incompatibilities among different library versions. The code will be run locally on a Jupyter Notebook on a macOS machine using the GPU if possible (I know that the TensorFlow-Metal library serves that purpose). The device and library versions, according to the lab activity, are as follows:
Device and OS: macOS Sonoma 14.6.1 with Intel i7 processor and AMD Radeon Pro 5300M GPU
Python: 3.8
Python libraries and versions:

Gym 0.17.3
git+https://github.com/Kojoley/atari-py.git
Pyglet 1.5.0
H5py 3.1.0
Pillow 9.5.0
Keras-RL2 1.0.5
Keras 2.2.4
TensorFlow 2.5.3
Torch 2.0.1
Agents 1.4.0

If anyone knows about the content of a requirements file, a YAML file, or similar, or how to install the additional packages that would be installed along with the Gym library with compatible versions, that would be great.
Thanks,
Javier

Thanks for the edit Maxim. It makes the question more readable
